# How to run a php project from within sublime text 2

Tags: php, sublimetext2

Is there a way to set up sublime text 2 to build (or run) a php script I'm editing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `Tools -> Build System -> New Build System...` and then edit the file like so:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/path/to/some/script/that/runs/your/project"]
}
```

Then save it, and from your project, select `Tools -> Build System -> <your new name>`

Now you can hit control-shift-b to run the script.

Answer (score 27):

if you are linux or mac user you can do that.

Tools -> Build System ->New Build System

```
{
 "cmd": ["php" , "$file"] 
}
```

It'll run your php codes on sublime text console

here is a screenshot if you wonder how does it look like.

[image]